# Let Apport catch crashes system-wide

Tags: apport

I want to let Apport catching all crashes - system wide - which means also crashes in programs which are located for example inside the HOME folder of a user and not part of Ubuntu packages. Is there any configuration option to realize this?

Silly example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("%n%n%n"); return 0; }

make test && ./test
```

Will create a crash but Apport will not intercept it.

CrashReporter on MacOS is able to create a crash report for all executable files regardless of where they are located in the system.

Comment: I did not mention anything about sending data. AFAIK Apport is not sending data, that's done by Whoopsie. I am personally only interested in having a .crash report on disk of a program which crashed in my HOME directory.

Comment: Yes, once a crash appears in the app, I see either "executable does not belong to a package, ignoring" or nothing in /var/log/apport.log (Perhaps because of SIGABRT - I think those exceptions are not getting logged in general).

Comment: When that comes up, is there a `.crash` file in `/var/crash`? If not, try checking *before* dismissing the dialog that says the but cannot be reported. If the `.crash` file is there, is there a problem using [these tools](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#Tools) (such as [`apport-unpack`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/apport-unpack.1.html)) to access the data in the file?

Comment: No .crash in /var/crash, and also no dialog. I have edited the question. If you like to test, try to compile and run the snippet. (Ignore the compile warnings.)

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but from reading the code I saw that you can enable crash reports for unpackaged binaries by creating a file called ~/.config/apport/settings with the content:

```
[main]
unpackaged=true
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It's the answer. I used ':' instead of '=', though but I guess '=' could work, too.